# Pagination in webDriver displays Stale Element Reference Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, junit4

Environment : Eclipse, Chrome, Java

I am dealing with test case for pagination in the application. I have tried with some code, but it moves only upto 2nd page.

Code :

```
List<WebElement> allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='pagination']//a"));
    System.out.println(allpages.size());
    if(allpages.size()>0)
    {
        System.out.println("Pagination exists");
        for(int i=0; i<allpages.size(); i++)
        {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            allpages.get(i).click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            //System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Pagination doesn't exists");
    }
}
```

Size displayed is 12. The issue is it moves upto 2nd page only and then displays error of StaleElementReference

Here's the HTML Code for the same pagination. 
HTML Code :

```
<div id="page-navigation" class="pull-right">
<div id="303b171e-5a26-e456" class="flex-view">
<div class="pagination">
<ul>
<li class="">
<a href="#" data-value="0">«</a>
</li>
<li class="" data-value="0">
<a href="#" data-value="0">1</a>
</li>
<li class="" data-value="1">
<a href="#" data-value="1">2</a>
</li>
<li class="active" data-value="2">
<a href="#" data-value="2">3</a>
</li>
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the new page is loaded after clicking one of the pagination links, the allpages WebElements are no longer valid and need to be found again.  You will have to put another call to `allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='pagination']//a"));` in your for loop so that you can get new references for each new page.

Comment: Thanks it worked :) I had even tried using while loop and iterate it :)